# Does files created by getExternalCacheDir() get deleted automatically or app has to delete explicitly

Tags: android, caching, external

I want to store an image in file system and once I am done with it I want to remove it. I have used getExternalStorageDirectory() and deleting files created in it after I am done. I got to see that getExternalCacheDir() is available and files in it should be deleted automatically as name says (cache).
  In the doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()) it says:
"The platform does not always monitor the space available in external storage, and thus may not automatically delete these files. Currently the only time files here will be deleted by the platform is when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 or later and Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated() returns true. Note that you should be managing the maximum space you will use for these anyway, just like with getCacheDir()."

I could not find clear info on WHEN platform deltes files though they say it does for JB_MR1 and later. Let me know if you've used it already.

I tried to find all the links related to getExternalCacheDir() but did not find that answer this. If there is one such post, please redirect me to that. Thanks!

Comment: I think the cache will be deleted when you click on 'Clear cache' button in settings.

Comment: I think yes. But if we know when it happens programatically then we can decide whether to use or not. Anyway I moved back to getExternalStorageDir() an then deleting on my own.

Answer (score 0):

getExternalCacheDir() returns a java.io.File object representing the cache of the application on the primary external storage. This cache is not visible to the user and is deleted when the application is uninstalled. There is no mechanism in the Android SDK to delete files in the cache directory, so you need to manage your cache to keep it to a reasonable maximum size. Starting with Android 4.4, the application does not need permission to access its own cache, but with older versions your application needs the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.